# Typehint googleapiclient.discovery.build returning value

Tags: python, type-hinting, google-api-python-client

I create the Google API `Resource` class for a specific type (in this case `blogger`).

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import Resource, build

def get_google_service(api_type) -> Resource:
    credentials = ...

    return build(api_type, 'v3', credentials=credentials)

def blog_service():
    return get_google_service('blogger')

def list_blogs():
    return blog_service().blogs()
```

The problem arises when using the function `list_blogs`.
As I am providing a specific service name, I know that the return value of `blog_service` has the method `blogs`, but my IDE doesn't recognize it.
Is there a way to annotate the `blog_service` function to inform my IDE about the existence of the `blogs` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `Resource` class **dynamically** sets arbitrary attributes/methods based on what [collections](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/start.md#collections) the underlying API provides.

In your case apparently there is a `blogs` collection, which means the `blogs` method is dynamically constructed on that `Resource` object.

Expecting **static** type annotations, when your types are created **dynamically** is a tall order. (I assume this is one of the reasons the maintainers of [`google-api-python-client`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/) do not even bother with type-hinting in that package.)

But depending on your goals with those functions, you might improve your IDE experience by using [**protocols**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/).

If you know that your `blog_service` function returns an object that has a `blogs` method, you can define a corresponding [protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol). The problem is of course kicked down the road because whatever that `blogs` method returns may also have arbitrary methods. But depending on if this is important to you, you can apply the same principle for that again.

The upside is that [`Resource`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/v2.90.0/googleapiclient/discovery.py#L1342) itself actually seems to have very few public methods, essentially just `close` and the context manager protocol. So you could emulate that in some sort of base protocol and use inheritance to construct different resource-protocols.

Here is an example to illustrate:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol, Self

from googleapiclient.discovery import build  # type: ignore[import]


class ResourceProtocol(Protocol):
    def close(self) -> None: ...

    def __enter__(self) -> Self: ...

    def __exit__(self, *args: Any) -> None: ...


class BloggerProtocol(ResourceProtocol):
    def blogs(self) -> Any: ...


def get_google_service(api_type: str) -> Any:
    credentials = ...
    return build(api_type, 'v3', credentials=credentials)


def blog_service() -> BloggerProtocol:
    return get_google_service('blogger')  # type: ignore[no-any-return]


def list_blogs() -> Any:
    return blog_service().blogs()
```

(Note that those are all *literal* ellipses `...`. Also, if you are on Python `<3.11`, you should be able to import [`Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) from `typing_extensions` instead.)

Now your IDE should be able to detect that the object returned by `blog_service` has a `blogs` method *and* can be used as a context manager (using `with`).

Notice that I annotated the return type of `blogs` as `Any` because I don't know what type it is supposed to return.